# Reducing API Requests for Cloud Run Services via Anthos Config Management

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-anthos, gcp-config-connector

I am currently provisioning GCP Cloud Run services using the Anthos Config Management. I have noticed in the logs that there are three attempts per second to retrieve service information from the Cloud Run API (Cloud RunGetService). The principal associated with these requests is the account linked to the Config Connector.

I have encountered quota limit errors on several occasions due to the high frequency of these requests. I am curious about the reasons behind these multiple attempts and would like to know if there is a way to reduce the number of requests to the API.

Your assistance and guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Summary:

```
2023-04-07T09:29:53.637281Z - google.cloud.run.v2.Services.GetService
2023-04-07T09:29:53.544169Z - google.cloud.run.v2.Services.GetService
2023-04-07T09:29:52.487437Z - google.cloud.run.v2.Services.GetService
2023-04-07T09:29:51.521130Z - google.cloud.run.v2.Services.GetService
2023-04-07T09:29:51.482940Z - google.cloud.run.v2.Services.GetService
2023-04-07T09:29:51.440035Z - google.cloud.run.v2.Services.GetService
```

```
[
  {
    "insertId": "6o7xwnd1apc",
    "logName": "projects/projectId/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access",
    "protoPayload": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
      "authenticationInfo": {
        "principalEmail": "anthos-config-managment-service-account",
        "principalSubject": "serviceAccount:anthos-config-managment-service-account"
      },
      "authorizationInfo": [
        {
          "granted": true,
          "permission": "run.services.get",
          "resource": "projects/projectId/locations/region/services/serviceName",
          "resourceAttributes": {}
        }
      ],
      "methodName": "google.cloud.run.v2.Services.GetService",
      "requestMetadata": {
        "callerIp": "10.156.0.8",
        "callerNetwork": "//compute.googleapis.com/projects/projectId/global/networks/__unknown__",
        "callerSuppliedUserAgent": "kcc/controller-manager blueprints/kpt-pkg-fn-live DeclarativeClientLib/0.0.1,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)",
        "destinationAttributes": {},
        "requestAttributes": {
          "auth": {},
          "time": "2023-04-07T09:29:53.658779Z"
        }
      },
      "resourceLocation": {
        "currentLocations": ["region"]
      },
      "resourceName": "projects/projectId/locations/region/services/serviceName",
      "serviceName": "run.googleapis.com"
    },
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-04-07T09:29:54.442225196Z",
    "resource": {
      "labels": {
        "configuration_name": "",
        "location": "region",
        "project_id": "projectId",
        "revision_name": "",
        "service_name": "serviceName"
      },
      "type": "cloud_run_revision"
    },
    "severity": "INFO",
    "timestamp": "2023-04-07T09:29:53.637281Z"
  },
  {
    "insertId": "y4uoutd1cbh",
    "logName": "projects/projectId/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access",
    "protoPayload": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
      "authenticationInfo": {
        "principalEmail": "anthos-config-managment-service-account",
        "principalSubject": "serviceAccount:anthos-config-managment-service-account"
      },
      "authorizationInfo": [
        {
          "granted": true,
          "permission": "run.services.get",
          "resource": "projects/projectId/locations/region/services/serviceName",
          "resourceAttributes": {}
        }
      ],
      "methodName": "google.cloud.run.v2.Services.GetService",
      "requestMetadata": {
        "callerIp": "10.156.0.8",
        "callerNetwork": "//compute.googleapis.com/projects/projectId/global/networks/__unknown__",
        "callerSuppliedUserAgent": "kcc/controller-manager blueprints/kpt-pkg-fn-live DeclarativeClientLib/0.0.1,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)",
        "destinationAttributes": {},
        "requestAttributes": {
          "auth": {},
          "time": "2023-04-07T09:29:53.561641Z"
        }
      },
      "resourceLocation": {
        "currentLocations": ["region"]
      },
      "resourceName": "projects/projectId/locations/region/services/serviceName",
      "serviceName": "run.googleapis.com"
    },
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-04-07T09:29:54.124104694Z",
    "resource": {
      "labels": {
        "configuration_name": "",
        "location": "region",
        "project_id": "projectId",
        "revision_name": "",
        "service_name": "serviceName"
      },
      "type": "cloud_run_revision"
    },
    "severity": "INFO",
    "timestamp": "2023-04-07T09:29:53.544169Z"
  },
  {
    "insertId": "170bquhc1db",
    "logName": "projects/projectId/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access",
    "protoPayload": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
      "authenticationInfo": {
        "principalEmail": "anthos-config-managment-service-account",
        "principalSubject": "serviceAccount:anthos-config-managment-service-account"
      },
      "authorizationInfo": [
        {
          "granted": true,
          "permission": "run.services.get",
          "resource": "projects/projectId/locations/region/services/serviceName",
          "resourceAttributes": {}
        }
      ],
      "methodName": "google.cloud.run.v2.Services.GetService",
      "requestMetadata": {
        "callerIp": "10.156.0.8",
        "callerNetwork": "//compute.googleapis.com/projects/projectId/global/networks/__unknown__",
        "callerSuppliedUserAgent": "kcc/controller-manager blueprints/kpt-pkg-fn-live DeclarativeClientLib/0.0.1,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)",
        "destinationAttributes": {},
        "requestAttributes": {
          "auth": {},
          "time": "2023-04-07T09:29:52.504497Z"
        }
      },
      "resourceLocation": {
        "currentLocations": ["region"]
      },
      "resourceName": "projects/projectId/locations/region/services/serviceName",
      "serviceName": "run.googleapis.com"
    },
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-04-07T09:29:53.491235721Z",
    "resource": {
      "labels": {
        "configuration_name": "",
        "location": "region",
        "project_id": "projectId",
        "revision_name": "",
        "service_name": "serviceName"
      },
      "type": "cloud_run_revision"
    },
    "severity": "INFO",
    "timestamp": "2023-04-07T09:29:52.487437Z"
  }]
```

Comment: can you share part of the logs if it is possible ?

Comment: @SRJ added to the description

Comment: Have you checked if this Cloud Run `GetService` API is called by any of your own software components somewhere using `anthos-config-managment-service-account` service account  ?

Comment: Of course, I've checked that as well, 100%. That is Anthos Config Management components. I'm just curious, what is the reason for bombarding the Cloud Run API so often? I mean, I can imagine that ACM wants to keep watching it to keep track of the desired state it is responsible for, but why so many :(